# Squeeze empty lines using powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I squeeze empty multiple blank lines, so that

```
AAA
AAA
AAA

BBB
BBB


CCC
```

into

```
AAA
AAA
AAA

BBB
BBB

CCC
```

using powershell.

The script

```
(gc test.tex).Trim() | Where-Object{$_ -notmatch "^\s*$"}
```

squeezes every single blank line, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file as a single string, trim leading/trailing whitespace, then collapse 2 or more consecutive newlines by replacing them with exactly 2 newlines.

```
(Get-Content test.txt -Raw).Trim() -replace '(\r?\n){2,}', '$1$1'
```

The parameter `-Raw` was introduced with PowerShell v3. If you're using an older version you could emulate the behavior by piping the output through `Out-String`:

```
(Get-Content test.txt | Out-String).Trim() -replace '(\r?\n){2,}', '$1$1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join expression:

```
@((Get-Content -Path test.tex).Trim()) -notmatch '^\s*$' -join "`n`n"
```

This filters out all the blank lines, then rejoins them with newline characters.  When operators are applied against collections, they implicitly act as filters (removing the need for `Where-Object` in this example).

---

For the case of keeping things matched up in their groups:

```
(Get-Content -Path test.tex -Raw) -replace '(?m)^\s*$'
```

This uses the multiline flag to capture those newline characters.

Comment: This doesn't actually do what I want since it inserts blank spaces between all items in the array. See updated issue text.

Comment: @mu7z Of course it doesn't do what you want.  You changed your entire question premise.

Comment: The question I now realize wasn't clear. (I didn't mean to change the `entire premise' which seems a bit excessive to say.)

Comment: @mu7z I've updated my answer to your new specification